# Web-scraping with Python: NoneType error, can't scrape table's data

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, nonetype

this is my first attempt at coding so please forgive my daftness. I'm trying to learn web scraping by practising with this link:
https://data.gov.sg/dataset/industrial-arbitration-court-awards-by-nature-of-trade-disputes?view_id=d3e444ef-54ed-4d0b-b715-1ee465f6d882&resource_id=c24d0d00-2d12-4f68-8fc9-4121433332e0

I've honestly spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my code here:

```
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/industrial-arbitration-court-awards-by-nature-of-trade-disputes?view_id=d3e444ef-54ed-4d0b-b715-1ee465f6d882&resource_id=c24d0d00-2d12-4f68-8fc9-4121433332e0'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody')

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.find('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        list_of_cells.append()
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./indarb.csv","wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
```

My terminal then spits out this: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find', saying there's an error in line 13. Not sure if it helps in queries but this is a list of what I've tried:

Different permutations of 'find'/'findAll'

- Instead of '.find', used '.findAll'
- Instead of '.findAll', used '.find'

Different permutations for line 10

- Tried soup.find('tbody')
- Tried soup.find('table')
- Opened source code, tried soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table table-condensed'})

Different permutations for line 13

- similarly tried with just 'tr' tag; or
- tried adding 'attrs={}' stuff

I've really tried but can't figure out why I can't scrape that simple 10 row table. If anyone could post code that works, that'd be phenomenal. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Have you actually looked in your browser or at what requests  returns to see what you get with that url?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I apologise for that mistake, it should be url = 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/industrial-arbitration-court-awards-by-nature-of-trade-disputes?view_id=d3e444ef-54ed-4d0b-b715-1ee465f6d882&resource_id=c24d0d00-2d12-4f68-8fc9-4121433332e0' 
Even after that though, the problem still occured.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you request in your code is not HTML but JSON.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks very much! Sorry still trying to understand what these terms all mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes, the biggest is you are using *BeautifulSoup3* which has not been developed for years, you should be use [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you also need to use `find_all` when you want want multiple tags. Also you have not passed cell to `list_of_cells.append()` on line 13 so that is the cause of your other error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://data.gov.sg/dataset/industrial-arbitration-court-awards-by-nature-of-trade-disputes?view_id=d3e444ef-54ed-4d0b-b715-1ee465f6d882&resource_id=c24d0d00-2d12-4f68-8fc9-4121433332e0%27'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table')

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        list_of_cells.append(cell)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)
```

I am not sure exactly what you want but that appends the tds from the first table on the page.  There is also and [api](https://data.gov.sg/api/1/util/snippet/api_info.html?resource_id=c24d0d00-2d12-4f68-8fc9-4121433332e0&datastore_root_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdata.gov.sg%2Fapi%2Faction) you can use and a[downloadable csv](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/c9e00712-1c65-4e0c-915a-2f145b193d33/resource/c24d0d00-2d12-4f68-8fc9-4121433332e0/download) if you do actually want the data.